# Use Android Auto App in Android Automotive Emulator

Tags: android, testing, transform, android-auto, android-automotive

I saw that there is a DHU for Testing Android Auto Apps during development.
At the same time, there is an Emulator with system images from Volvo and Polestar to use Android Automotive in Android Studio.

I found this on Google Android Auto webpage:

> You enable Android Auto to connect with your phone app by creating
> services that Android Auto uses to display a driver-optimized
> interface to the driver. You reuse these services for your Android
> Automotive OS app, but users do not install your phone app on their
> cars.

I was wondering if I develop some app for Android Auto, how complicated is the process of transforming this app to use it in Android Emulator or as an Android Automotive App?

The whole let's say business logic behind Apps should stay the same and services, according to Google, should work on Automotive as well? So the only difference is in UI?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take media app as an example

It isn't complex, there is step-by-instructions at https://developer.android.com/cars to port your Android Auto app to Android Automotive OS.